# Having trouble understanding which IP to allocate to bond0?

Tags: bonding

I am having trouble understanding which IP to allocate to bond0 while performing NIC bonding.

Comment: It will be good if you can provide me more information about your system environment and also the things which you already tried.

Comment: dear i am trying it to do in centos 6.9.

Answer (score 1):

you set one IP@ to the bound0  but not on its nics

for the nics allocated to bound0 you just say master is the bound0

for example

ifcfg-bond0 :

```
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=172.76.1.3
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
BROADCAST=172.76.0.255
GATEWAY=172.76.1.100
USERCTL=no
```

ifcfg-eth0 :

```
DEVICE=eth0
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

ifcfg-eth1 :

```
DEVICE=eth1
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

the IP@ depends on your own network so no one will say witch one to use.

Comment: i mean to say how to you determine the ip adress to allocate to bond0

Comment: another problem occurring is that ifconfig does not show bond0.

Comment: bond0 is your creation it will not appear on devices list  that's normal